# Adapting CSV file to HighStock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to make a simple **Highstock graph** (similar to [this](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line)). I think I understood the example from documentation.

In my case, it is not a JSON file but a **CSV** from Yahoo Finance API. 
Example :

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2010-01-25,39.965,41.57,39.115,41.225,5301000,33.403
2010-01-18,41.75,42.93,40.13,40.465,4340200,32.787
2010-01-11,44.285,44.435,41.375,41.565,4399300,33.678
2010-01-04,43.46,44.85,43.35,44.02,2939200,35.667
```

(From [Yahoo](http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=31&f=2010&g=w&ignore=.csv))

Answer (score 0):

When you load CSV (by `$.get()`) then you need to parse your data.

Example of parser:

```
                    var lines = data.split('\n'),
                        tmptimestamp = '',
                        serie = {
                            name: seriesName,
                            data: [],
                            showInLegend:true
                        };

                    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                        var items = line.split(',');

                        if ((lineNo && items[0].length) > 0) {
                            var date = items[0].split('-'),
                            timestamp = Date.UTC(parseFloat(date[2]),parseFloat(date[0])-1,parseFloat(date[1]));

                            serie.data.push({
                                x: timestamp,
                                y: parseFloat(items[1])
                            });
                        }
                    });

//Highcharts init
```